# Выборка из mysql "где сумма значение таких-то равно [число]"

Tags: sql, mysql

Приветствую!

Есть ли способ, не мудрствуя лукаво, сделать такого рода выборку? Поясню подробнее: 
есть записи в таблице, у каждой имеется цена, и количество. 
Задача: сделать выборку тех полей, сумма умноженная на количество которых равна Х?

записи должны выбраться в пределах одного поля (номера заказа), т.е. Сумма должна считаться только в пределах одного номера заказа.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Тогда так:

```
select * from 
         ( select sum(table.price*table.cnt) as test_value, 
                  table.some_field 
             from table 
           group by table.some_field ) as t2 
where t2.test_value = X
```

Comment: т.е. правильно я понимаю, что Вам надо подсчитать сумму sum(price*count) в разрезе группы по третьему полю и выбрать только те у которых эта сумма равна определённому числу?

Comment: работает!! Спасибо! еще один момент не поможете? 
Ситуация такая, вот, что получилось у нас с Вами
*SELECT * FROM ( SELECT sum( sum * quantity ) AS test_value, order_id, sum *FROM orders WHERE present=1 AND neotgruz=0 GROUP BY order_id ) AS t2 WHERE *t2.test_value =11800 
теперь надо из другой таблицы взять информацию о скидке для этого заказа (в %), затем получить сумму с учетом скидки, и искать уже эту сумму..
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: @Ozim, Вам надо во вложенный запрос добавить джойн таблицы скидки по order_id и в sum добавить эту скидку sum(sum`*`quantity`*`sale). Думаю справитесь

Comment: неа, сам не справлюсь, но и на том спасибо :)

Comment: @Ozim, я в вас верю, там ничего сложного :-) У Вас между from и group by появиться что то типа `left join sale_table on (sale_table.order_id = table.order_id)` и почти успех :-)

Comment: попробовал 


SELECT * FROM ( SELECT sum( sum * quantity ) AS test_value, order_id, sum FROM orders WHERE present=1 AND neotgruz=0 left join orderdata on (orderdata.order_id = orders.order_id) GROUP BY order_id ) AS t2 WHERE t2.test_value =11800 

не работает :(

Comment: @Ozim, 

>`между from и group by появиться`

вы вставили туда ещё и where зачем-то. Если это ограничение на джоин таблицу - то добавте условиями в on (.. and present =1 and neotgruz = 0)

Comment: получилось) немного не так, без join (ну не понимаю я его)

SELECT t2 . * , o.skidka
FROM (

SELECT sum( sum * quantity ) AS test_value, order_id
FROM orders
WHERE present =1
AND neotgruz =0
GROUP BY order_id
) AS t2, orderdata o
WHERE CEILING( t2.test_value - FLOOR( t2.test_value /100 * o.skidka ) ) =11800
AND t2.order_id = o.order_id

еще раз, большая благодарность.

Answer (score 0):

```
select price, cnt, ordernum from table group by table.ordernum, table.price, table.cnt having sum(table.price*table.cnt) = X order by 3
```

Comment: зачем группировать по цене и номеру заказа? Переделал чуток, но не то http://joxi.ru/dJzWUv3JTJD7ZKhsLm0